# How to get the value from a dynamic variable in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]

Trying to do this.

Trying to create the variable dynamically and then read the value out of that variable in a loop.

```
@ECHO off

SET SQL1=TEST
SET SQL2=TEST1
SET SQL3=TEST2
SET SQL=SQL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A number=0

FOR /l %%A IN (1,1,3) DO (

SET /A number = number + 1
echo !number!
    echo %SQL%!number!

)
endlocal

Output should be 
 1
 test
 2
 test2
 3
 test3
I am getting 
 C:\temp>c.bat
  1
  SQL1
  2
  SQL2
  3
  SQL3
```

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugh.

First way (note that instead of your `number` variable, it uses the loop counter variable `%%A`):

```
@ECHO off

SET SQL1=TEST
SET SQL2=TEST1
SET SQL3=TEST2

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A number=0

FOR /l %%A IN (1,1,3) DO (

SET /A number = number + 1
echo !number!
echo !SQL%%A!

)
endlocal
```

Second way (ugly but it does what you want):

```
@ECHO off

SET SQL1=TEST
SET SQL2=TEST1
SET SQL3=TEST2

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A number=0

FOR /l %%A IN (1,1,3) DO (

SET /A number = number + 1
echo !number!
for %%i in (!number!) do (echo !SQL%%i!)

)
endlocal
```

Comment: omg, spend all day to figure this out. thank you so much. I am using the 1st way.

Comment: If you're using the first way, note that you don't need your `number` variable at all.