# Is it possible to have a variable name include other variables?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have a batch file I am working on that I need to have a variable name be changeable.  What I mean by this is I have a list of variables named `%X0Y0U%` to `%X9Y9U%` all of which are either set to 1 or 0 and one of the variables is set to 2(this can change if needed).  I have a later part of the batch file do this:

```
set TEMPLOC=X%Xcoord%Y%Ycoord%U
if %TEMPLOC% EQU 1 (
     random code
) ELSE if %TEMPLOC% EQU 0 (
     random code
) ELSE if %TEMPLOC% EQU 2 (
     random code
)
```

Then the batch file has a part I know works already.  What I need to know is how I can have `%TEMPLOC%` equal the value of the variable `%X#Y#U%`.  The `#'s` are representing a number between `0` and `9` and are not always the same for both of the `#'s`.  I would like to, in short, be able to do this (this is a very literal version of it) `%X %Xcoord% Y %Ycoord% U%` , minus the spaces.  I do know that what I have stated is not possible as it will read as `%X% Xcoord %Y% Ycoord %U%` , again minus the spaces.  Please help me as I am very puzzled as to how to do this.

If you do not understand or need me to add more of my code, **please** say so in the comments.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve? Basically you code could check all possible combinations for equality but do you really want to such code?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999327/), it might help you.

Comment: @Laf Just curious, but why did you remove my "Thanks in advance" from my question?

Comment: Because it is not proper form to post "thanks" and "Hi" lines when posting a question here. These lines are removed from all questions, so it's not only your question ;)

Comment: Ok thank you for telling me this.  I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Delayed Expansion for this; this way, the line is parsed and expanded in two stages: the first expansion works over variables enclosed in percent signs, and the second expansion works on variables enclosed in exclamation marks (as long as the Delayed Expansion be enabled). For example:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Xcoord=3
set Ycoord=6
set TEMPLOC=!X%Xcoord%Y%Ycoord%U!
```

**EDIT**: *Second method added*

If the value of X%Xcoord%Y%Ycoord%U variable is a number, you may also do the same thing without Delayed Expansion via `SET /A` command:

```
set /A TEMPLOC=X%Xcoord%Y%Ycoord%U
```

Comment: Just checking, but will your edit give the value of the wanted variable? Example: `set X1Y1U=1 set /a TEMPLOC=X%Xcoord%Y%Ycoord%U` Will `%TEMPLOC%=1` when echoed? Also if I were to use the first example you gave, where should I put the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`?  Should I put it in the first few lines of the batch file along with `@echo off`? Thanks

Comment: @Burn_E99 - Yes, both methods are equivalent and will give the correct answer as long as the value is always numeric. If the value may be non-numeric, then you should use method 1. Typically, the `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` appears near the top, after `@echo off`. However, there are situations where it is not that simple. But that is a whole topic in and of itself.

Comment: Thanks I think I will be using your set /a version as it is more straightforward and since I do not know much (none actually) about the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to use either method posted by Aacini. But another (much slower) way to do it without delayed expansion is:

```
call set TEMPLOC=%%X%Xcoord%Y%Ycoord%%%
```

The CALL creates two normal expansion phases.

If both Xcoord and Ycoord are 1, then during the first expansion phase:

```
%Xcoord%  --> 1
%Ycoord%  --> 1
%%        --> %
```

yielding:

```
%X1Y1%
```

Then the second CALL expansion phase will get your desired value.

You can chain many CALL statements together, doubling the outer percents each time.

But, again, I don't like to use this method except under rare circumstances.